# SSO Authentication in Jenkins

Tags: authentication, jenkins, single-sign-on

I want to use SSO for Jenkins without going through LDAP. I tried using URL Auth plugin for this purpose. It is confusing and complicated. Plus I couldn't find any proper documentation for it on web.

Can anyone please help me understanding how to use it? Links to proper documentation around it is as well appreciated.